# NamedPipeClientStream - Notifications if server has disconnected

Tags: .net-core, notifications, named-pipes

I have a question and I couldn't find any answer here.
I am using the `NamedPipeClientStream/NamedPipeServerStream` classes for bidirectional IPC communication in a .NET 5.0/.NET Framework 4.8 environment and it works fine, however I need to have a way of letting the client (immediately) know if the server is not running anymore and I am not sure what is the best way to achieve this.

Of course I can try on the client side to call `Connect` with a timeout every 3 seconds for example and if I get a `TimeoutException`, then it means the server is not available, however as far I as have read, doing this (for example with a timer and/or a background thread) is not very efficient. Are there better ways to do this (and still use named pipes)? Can someone point me in another (better) direction?

I had it solved before with WCF, however as .NET Core doesn't support it, it is not a solution anymore.

Thank you very much.
BR,
M.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a twofold approach where if a server shuts down nicely you send a 'i am shutting down' message to the client. And also have the server send small heartbeat messages once per second to clients. This way clients can check if the last heartbeat is stale or the server has shutdown whenever they need.

Looking for a WCF replacement myself and came across your post ;-)